# How do I pass the onClick parameter in this one?

Tags: kotlin, authentication, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

This is my OTP screen function to receive and read OTP.
The function has the 2 parameters as shown,

```
fun OTPScreen(
    navController : NavController,
    onClick: (mobileNum: String,otp: String) -> Unit,
)
```

This is my `navhost` function that navigates to the OTP screen.
Can someone tell me how do I pass the onClick parameter in this case?

```
composable(
    route = Screen.Otpscreen.route,
) {  
    OTPScreen(navController = navController, onClick = (" "))
}
```

I'm new to jetpack and functions are always confusing.
Let me know if I need to elaborate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with compose but assuming it works like any other kotlin you could write it like this

```
OTPScreen(navController = navController, onClick = {mobileNum, otp ->
    //your code here
})
```

as noted by Karsten Gabriel, this can also be written shorter as

```
OTPScreen(navController) { mobileNum, otp -> 
  //your code here
}
```

Or, if you want to use an existing function like

```
fun myFunction(mobileNum: String, otp: String) {
    //your code here
}
```

for example you can use that like

```
OTPScreen(navController = navController, onClick = ::myFunction)
```

Comment: maybe it is also noteworthy that it is not mandatory to write the parameter names, allowing to write the curly braces outside the parenthesis: `OTPScreen(navController) { mobileNum, otp -> /* your code here */ }`.

Comment: @KarstenGabriel good point. I added it to the answer